# Cacti NaN values

Tags: linux, php, monitoring, cacti

Firstly, when I create cacti graph using data input method (PHP script) is does not create rrd file which it should do. Still, when I copy command which is shown when I turn debug mode on and run it manually, rrd file is created. After that graph is shown but all values ar NaN.
I looked in cacti.log which gives me nothing, permissions to needed folders are set to 777, my php script returns me data in format :, for example, humidity:20.0.
Device status is up. Everything, as I think, must be correct.
Poller_output table in mysql is with max approximately 4000-5000 rows, but it is being truncated by Cacti, so it is not the problem.
What else can I do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are a LOT of variables that could cause it. Best thing to do is:

First, wait for the next poll. A graph can't be generated until there are at least two data points, and NaN will always show after the first poll.

Second, go through [the whole debugging process in the Cacti documentation](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/debugging.html).

Comment: I've created graph about 4 days ago and it should be visible now.
I'll try that debugging, although I tried it once.